# JS - CSV URL.createObjectURL(blob) not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jsgrid

I'm generating CSV from JSON. All works fine till the point when the cached in the browser files needs to be downloaded. I've tested Chrome, Safari, IE, Edge and Firefox. From all the browsers only Firefox does not download the file. I'm using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function JSONToCSV(JSONData, JSONHeader, PageName) {
        var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;
        var arrHeader = typeof JSONHeader != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONHeader) : JSONHeader;

        var CSV = '';

        // ADD Headers
        var row = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < arrHeader.length; i++) {
            row += '"' + arrHeader[i].title + '",';
        }
        row = row.slice(0, -1);
        CSV += row + '\r\n';

        // ADD Data
        for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
            var row = "";
            for (var index in arrData[i]) {
                if (index == "action_date") {
                    row += '"' + moment(arrData[i][index]).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss") + '",';
                }
                else {
                    row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
                }
            }
            row = row.slice(0, -1);
            CSV += row + '\r\n';
        }

        var FileName = PageName + "." + moment().format('DDMMYYYY') + ".csv";
        var blob = new Blob([CSV], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
        if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
            navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, FileName);
        } 
        else {
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            if (link.download !== undefined) { 
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.setAttribute('href', url);
                link.setAttribute('download', FileName);
                link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                console.log(link);
                link.click();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.body.removeChild(link);
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                }, 100);            
            }
        }
    }

  $("#ExportToExcel").on('click', function (event) {
    var filename = (window.location.pathname).substr(1);
    filename = filename.substring(0, filename.indexOf('/'));
    var data = $('#jsGrid').jsGrid('option', 'data');
    var header = $('#jsGrid').jsGrid('option', 'fields');
    JSONToCSV(data, header, filename);
  });

});
```

What am I doing wrong. On all the pages there is an information to either add the delay or adding element to the DOM which I'm doing and still no joy.

I found the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8wos7cf8/ that works in Firefox, so I have copied the code to my application completely overwriting what I wrote and it still does not work. I've tested Firefox on OSX and Windows and both are not downloading the cached file. I need to be doing something wrong but I cannot see what it is.

Comment: This was not my fiddle, found it when I was trying to find the solution for my problem. I have created a new one with all the changes that I did in my code and it's working [https://jsfiddle.net/djmbmkqe/](https://jsfiddle.net/djmbmkqe/) in the fiddle but not in my code.

Comment: fiddle updated [https://jsfiddle.net/djmbmkqe/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/djmbmkqe/2/)